# Roku BrightScript get application install date, possible?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I try t find the way to fetch application install date.

Since there is no API I thought to use Roku [File System](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/File+System) and verify create date of one of files for example under `pkg:`

Is it posible?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible in a different way - use `roRegistrySection`. When the app starts, check if some key - say "install_date" - exists. If not, this is the first time it is started, create that key and plant the current timestamp there. Next time the app starts it will be able to determine when it was first installed from there.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to revive an old question, but this does not have a proper answer.

The OP was on the right track with the idea of using the `roFileSystem` component, no need to use the registry.

Is as simple as:
`buildDate = createObject("roFileSystem").Stat("pkg:/manifest").ctime`

The `ctime` property is a [roDateTime](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/components/rodatetime.md) object, you can extract any date/time related info from it.

Answer (score 0):

I keep some utility functions for that purpose:

Drop these into a Device.brs file.

```
function regRead(key, section=invalid)
    if section = invalid then section = "Default"
    sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", section)
    if sec.Exists(key) then return sec.Read(key)
    return invalid
end function

function regWrite(key, val, section=invalid)
    if section = invalid then section = "Default"
    sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", section)
    sec.Write(key, val)
    sec.Flush() 'commit it
end function

function regDelete(key, section=invalid)
    if section = invalid then section = "Default"
    sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", section)
    sec.Delete(key)
    sec.Flush()
end function
```

Then you can check the previous version when the channel starts up:

```
version = regRead("application.version")
```

or update the version:

```
regWrite("application.version", "2.5")
```